# Expo detached project custom font does not work on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I eject my Expo project to Expokit as i want to slowly switch back to react-native

I tried too add custom fonts using

`react-native link`

And the font work fine on iOs but not on Android

The fonts was copied to `main/assets/fonts`
[image]

but i still got this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding this line to your package.json .

```
"rnpm": {
"assets": [
"./assets/fonts/"
]
```

}

and run :

```
react-native link
```

Comment: check if your font is here : android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/

If not try adding it manually and should be working then.

Comment: yes, the font was copied, i said that in the question.

Comment: I had similar issue but going through each step of this documentation from sratch helped me :https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

Comment: I also did go through that tutorial but it's for pure react-native project , mine is an expo detached project or expokit project.